# How to Pass ArryList or Array of Objects From C# to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, linq, object, client-side

I am creating `list` using `linq` in c# as following way and it works fine.

```
lst = (from n in dbEntity.Popup_Notes
       select n).ToList();
```

Now, I want to **use this list from client side as array of objects**. When user clicks on links, it will display specific notes descriptions as per name selection.

**EDIT**

i want something like this..

[image]

Comment: Is this a webform or MVC application?

Comment: webforms, a simple asp.net form with c#(4.0)

Comment: why do you need the list on the client side? Because of the client side/server side boundary, i would try to create a web api to return jason object of the list...

Comment: @will: if any possible solutions are also appreciated

Comment: I just need a little more info... can you explain why you need the list on the client side?

Comment: i want to display "help text" on "help button or mouse over" that comes from database. so, i am trying to load all help text on page load and then trying to display on click from client side.

Comment: Sorry, i'm still trying to understand your problem... are you trying to display some plain text (loaded from db) in a tooltip to the user. A visual or more concrete example may help, but right now i'm not understanding, for fun google qtip2.

Comment: @will: yes, some thing like tooltip.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27607/discussion-between-will-and-mm-tac)

Comment: Can you post some sample code from the client side? (and maybe add a link to a site that has similar functionality?)

Comment: @will: unfortunately, i failed to find similar thing that i want. For more info, i have added image, so you can get basic ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need convert your list to JSON and return to client-side. At client, you can use knockout.js to bind data to your control, this way is easier than binding manually.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. can you post some example code or reference links ?

Comment: The following code demo how to use knockout.js and bind data:
`var dataModel;

function view(data) {
    var self = this;
    
    this.DescriptionA = ko.observable(data.descriptionA);
    this.DescriptionB = ko.observable(data.descriptionB);
}

$(function(){
    dataModel = new view({"descriptionA": "Test A", "descriptionB": "Test B"});
    ko.applyBindings(dataModel);
});`
As you see I bind data when I initialize `View` object. This is the demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WkZr9/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)

Serialize your object(s) to JSON to pass it to your JavaScript code.

In your javascript code use [jQuery.parseJson](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to parse JSON text and build javascript object(s) according to the received JSON text.